# php - Test HTML Tag Names Above the Body Tag

Tags: php

I am trying to check a html doc's to make sure the tags above the body tag are correct. If it finds one that is wrong to remove it.

The following is a list of accepted tags I want to test for.

```
<head>
<title>
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```

I have a html page that has a anchor tag in the head section, which it should not so I would want that whole tag removed.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta>
<title></title>
<meta>
<link> 
<style></style>
<script></script>
<a></a>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
```

I used the code below to list out the tag names. It does not list them in order on the doc, but in the order it should be as if it is correcting the html structure.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($nodes as $item ){

echo $item->nodeName.'<br>';

}
```

It actually moved the open body tag in front of the misplace anchor tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta>
<title></title>
<meta>
<link> 
<style></style>
<script></script>
<body>    
<a></a>
<script></script>
```

Any thoughts or suggestion on how to test that the html tags that are above the open body tag are correct and remove those that are not would be appreciated.

Comment: Your script is just getting all the elements and listing them--I presume you know that? Because you've got error suppression turned on, it isn't able to throw an error at the `<a>` element in the head. DOMDocument already has a `recover` mode that will fix (to some extent) malformed HTML--there is no point in reinventing the wheel; use the tools that are already there.

Comment: Yep...knew all it was doing was listing the elements. So your suggestion is turn off error suppression...will look into it. Thanks

Comment: If I remove the `@` from `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`, PHP says "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity" and "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag in Entity".

Comment: When I remove it I get nothing but the list so I will have to figure out the error suppression issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument will give warnings if it encounters unexpected tags in the head or body of the document, so you can enable error reporting in your script and use the output from DOMDocument as a guide to whether your HTML is up to snuff. Using the sample above:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);      // turn error display on
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // display all errors!

$html = '<html>
<head>
<meta>
<title></title>
<meta>
<link>
<style></style>
<script></script>
<a></a>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>';

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);  // don't suppress errors when loading the HTML
```

This gives the output:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity, line: 11 in test.php on line 24
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced  tag in Entity, line: 12 in test.php on line 24

You can save the document and the misplaced elements will be moved into their correct position:

```
echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta><title></title><meta><link><style></style><script></script></head><body><a></a>
<script></script><article></article></body></html>
```

Note that the doctype gets set to html 4.0 loose by default, and that the `<a>` element is now in the body; any html5 tags, such as `<article>` or `<section>` get deleted.

Having said all that, if you want to verify your document syntax, you are better off running your html through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (which you can download and install locally) or the [nu validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/), which adds (partial) html5 validation, as libxml, which DOMDocument acts as an interface for, does not validate html5 documents.

Comment: @i alarmed alien -  I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question.  Searched your suggestion and came up pretty much with what you wrote for showing the error's and actually push the code from the url to w3c api for validation. I guess the end result I am looking for is automatically removing the error's specifically above the open body tag and have not figured out how to do that. May need to rethink this one.

Comment: There's an [HTML5 tidy](http://w3c.github.io/tidy-html5/) project on github which may be helpful. I've just added a bit on saving the HTML using DOMDocument. The trouble is that both libxml and the PHP tidy extension only work for html 4 and below, and they remove tags that they don't recognise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would consider using the [Tidy](http://php.net/tidy) extension, whose sole purpose for existing is to tidy up your markup? :)